# Restrict access to Java Packages for other Java Packages

Tags: java, static-code-analysis

Let us say I have three public java packages:

```
my.com.model
my.com.view
my.com.controler
```

Now I want to restrict which package is allowed to import classes from a dedicated package.

So e.g. the classes from view package are only allowed to import classes from controler package 
but not from model package and the controler package is only allowed to import classes from model package but
not from the view package and the model package has no access at all to the model and view packages.

How can I achieve this? I know that Java does not support such a requirement so maybe some static code
analysis tool can help me.

**Update:** I am using Java 7

Comment: Split them up over different modules, and only declare dependencies on the modules you want to make accessible.

Comment: You can do that with AspectJ. See the following blog. If someone has the time for it, feel free to turn it into an answer. https://blog.jayway.com/2010/03/28/architectural-enforcement-with-aid-of-aspectj/

Comment: So, to summarize: if you have modules support (will become native as of Java9, for now available with other tools) - then declare modules with right dependencies. If you have AspectJ with compile-time weaving enabled - you can use that, as suggested in linked article. If you have neither - you're probably out of luck, since there's no way of doing it in Java without those tools. In latter case you will have to setup a rigorous review process and indulge in handslapping.

Comment: Starting with JDK 9, you can use `module`s to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You could define this by extracting each concern in a separated module.

The view module would have a dependency on the controller module and  the controller module would have a dependency on the model module.

You could use Maven to achieve these constraints.

You could for example define a reactor or a multi module Maven project with 3 modules.

Maven provides transitive dependencies for a declared dependency. So to respect fully your requirements, the `view` module should exclude the transitive `model` dependency that is pulled by the `controller` dependency .